# How to ensure uniqueness of properties in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a requirement that the value of a particular field in documents of a collection need to be unique. This collection is partitioned, so I cannot write a trigger or SP to ensure this before each insert (as I want to ensure the uniqueness for whole collection and not just the partition).

I've come across the following links where it is mentioned that there is a uniqueKeyPolicy which can be added to a collection , but couldn't see any examples or more info in official documentation.

What's the best way to do this?

Information I found: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/changelog.md - Adds the ability to specify unique indexes for the documents by using UniqueKeyPolicy property on the DocumentCollection.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.uniquekeypolicy.uniquekeys?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.uniquekey?view=azure-dotnet

Update: After some trying, I was able to do this using the DocumentClient from my .NET code while creating a new collection(Non Partitioned) . But is there a way to add this constraint for an existing collection. Also I couldn’t find a way of doing this from the portal. Is there any particular place I should be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no way to do cross partition unique keys and unique keys can only be defined during collection creation. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys?view=azure-dotnet):

> Unique keys must be defined when the container is created, and the
>   unique key is scoped to the partition key. To build on the earlier
>   example, if you partition based on zip code, you could have the
>   records from the table duplicated in each partition.
>
> Existing containers cannot be updated to use unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Cosmos DB's DocumentDB API does not currently offer unique indexes for a property. This feature is listed as "started", on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/7329344-unique-constraint-on-document-properties). Perhaps there is some preparation work taking place to support unique indexes, but currently there is no official documentation stating they exist, or how to use them if they do exist.</strike>

**EDIT** It appears this feature has recently rolled out, as evidenced by the update to the .net SDK release notes. <strike>No official documentation published yet.</strike> Documentation is now published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: This looks to have changed since last week. I was able to create such collection from c# document client. Updated my question accordingly.